# AFNetworking 1.3 shipped with RestKit does not support IPv6

Tags: ios, afnetworking, restkit

Apple recently started to refuse apps that connect to a non-ipv6 enabled backend servers, and also networking tools such as `AFNetworking` versions prior to `3.0` do not support `IPv6`, so even if the server has been updated to support `IPv6` we need to to update our networking tools too.

we have an app that uses `Reskit 0.27.0` which is bundled with `AFNetworking 1.3`, is it possible to update `RestKit`'s `AFNetworking` version to `3` or should we remove `RestKit` from the app?

Comment: Raise the issue in RestKit Github Repository https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 is supported by `NSURLConnection`, and hence `AFNetworking` and `RestKit`. IPv6 support is generally more about using a domain name rather than an explicit IP address anyway. So, if you have issues, they lie somewhere other than in the networking library used by RestKit.

Check the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition/UnderstandingandPreparingfortheIPv6Transition.html) for related info.

As for the migration to AFN3, it's hard. Some people are / have been working on it, and there are forks with that work. They can be found via the RestKit issues related to the topic.